# understanding how a cohomlogy functor can be a right derived functor of a left exact functor

Tags: homological-algebra

My supervisor has been telling me about how you can understand a cohomology functor as a right derived functor of a left exact functor. We were talking about two specific examples, the cohomology of a topological space with respect to a sheaf, and the cohomology of a group with respect to a representation. Is there any source written in English which might help me understand this better, for someone who isn't a huge expert in homological algebra?

Comment: Maybe you find the beginning of my answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038292/why-can-we-use-flabby-sheaves-to-define-cohomology/1038346#1038346 helpful.

Comment: "Is there any source written in English which might help me understand this better, for someone who isn't a huge expert in homological algebra?" -- maybe a homological algebra textbook?