# Computing Tor using flat resolutions

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I am reading Matsumura's book *Commutative Algebra*, second edition. Doing a proof(3.E) in the chapter about flatness the author appears to assume that the reader knows that one can use flat projections of an $A$-module $M$ to compute $\mathrm{Tor}_i^A(M,N)$.

Is this legitimate?

Where can I find a reference of this?

Comment: Matsumura's book *Commutative Ring Theory* has an appendix from where you can learn quickly what Tor is.

Comment: You find some general information about which resolutions are suitable for computing derived functors in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1038292/why-can-we-use-flabby-sheaves-to-define-cohomology/1038346#1038346

Comment: Flat modules are precisely the Tor-acyclic modules (an $A$-module $M$ is said to be _Tor-acyclic_ if $\operatorname{Tor}_A^i(M,N)=0$ for all $i>0$ and all $R$-modules $N$). Then one uses Leray's acyclicity lemma.

Answer (score 2):

One can in general prove that if $F:A\to B$ is a functor between abelian categories with enough projectives, the following holds. For every $F$-acyclic resolution $C_* \to M$ of an object $M$ of $A$, it is true that
$$L_iF(M) \simeq H_i(FC_*)$$

To do this, one uses the horseshoe lemma to construct a "resolution" $R_{**}$ of the augmented complex $C_* \to M$: $R_{**}$ is a bicomplex of projective modules with exact rows and such that each column is a resolution of $C_i$ ($C_0=M$). In particular its first column is a projective resolution $P_*\to M$ of $M$. Now consider the bicomplex $F_{**}$ obtained by deleting the $P_*$ from $R_{**}$. There are maps of bicomplexes ($FP_*$ and $FC_*$ being one column bicomplexes) obtained from the edge arrows of the bigger double complex (draw a picture)

$$\eta : F F_{**} \to FP_*$$
$$\nu : FF_{**} \to FC_*$$
and I claim $\operatorname{Tot}(\eta)$ and $\operatorname{Tot}(\nu)$ are quasi-isomorphisms. To see this, one notes the cone of such morphisms are acyclic. Now the cone of $\operatorname{Tot}(\eta)$ is the total complex of $FR_{**}$ minus $FC_*$, and the rows of this complex are acyclic because the $P_*$, being projective, are $F$-acyclic. Similarly, the cone of $\operatorname{Tot}(\nu)$ is $FR_{**}$ minus $FP_*$, and the columns of this complex are acyclic since the $C_*$ are $F$-acyclic. It follows both maps are quasi-isomorphisms, so

$$L_i F(M) = H_i(FP_*) \simeq H_i(\operatorname{Tot}(FF_{**})) \simeq H_i(FC_*)$$

as desired.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty important, so I guess it can be found in some form in most of the introductory homological algebra books. One reference is Rotman's *Introduction to Homological algebra*, Theorem 7.5 (on the first glance, the proof given there seems somewhat computational, but that also means elementary, so why not).

Comment: Incidentally, the proof in Rotman's book contains a mistake. The author maintains a list of typo on his website and one can find a corrected version there.